# How to get /test/?grid-view or /test/?list-view' in Django view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a page that can be viewed by list or grid view through jQuery, but I want the URL to display what view it is -- especially when user paginate so that they don't have to reclick what they want to view -- so something like this: `/test/?grid_view` or `/test/?list_view`.

I've been trying to use `request.GET.get`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is what I have so far:

```
def test (request):
    grid_view = request.GET.get('grid_view')
    list_view = request.GET.get('list_view')
    if grid_view:
        return render_to_response('grid_view.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    elif list_view:
        return render_to_response('list_view.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('default_view.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then in my main template I'd point the different views to `<a href="/?list_view/">list view</a>`, etc. There is probably a better way to do it so any suggestions are appreciated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string is evaluated to False and, that is what your GET request Query String parameters will contain.

You could modify your code to:

```
if 'grid_view' in request.GET or 'grid_view/' in request.GET:
    pass
elif 'list_view' in request.GET or 'list_view/' in request.GET:
    pass
```

Or:

```
if request.GET.has_key('grid_view') or request.GET.has_key('grid_view/'):
# ...
```

Comment: The link `<a href="/?list_view/>list view</a>` will have a key of `list_vew/` not `list_view`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a GET parameter. Use `request.META['QUERY_STRING']` to get the query string.