# Django templates - is it possible to make url-aware templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Is it possible to make a django template URL aware without javascript?

For example, I would like to modify the css class to "active" for a certain tab or pill in twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I have asked a similar question, and the chosen answer provides example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662391/how-to-get-test-grid-view-or-test-list-view-in-django-view. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `request` available in context then you can use [request.path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes) within the template to know the url and make css class `active` or `inactive` based on that.
You need to add `django.core.context_processors.request` in your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in project settings.

Alternatively just pass a `page_name` in request context and use that.

As `arie` pointed out: check [django-activelink](https://github.com/j4mie/django-activelink#readme) which basically seems to use the same above approach I mentioned but it adds some template tags on top.

Comment: You might take a look at [django-activelink](https://github.com/j4mie/django-activelink#readme) which basically seems to use this approach and adds some template tags on top.

Comment: @arie thanks for the tip +1 on comment, can I add this in actual answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but the resulting template code will be a bit hard to read. Adding a lot of logic to the template reduces/removes the separation-of-concerns advantage of MVC.

What you need to do is pass the request info to the template, and the easiest way to do that is to add a template context processor. Put something like this in your settings.py:

```
from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

You can then access the request.path info in your template and construct logic to alter the output depending on your needs.

Comment: thanks! I had also considered @Aamir Adnan's answer also, but wanted to make it somewhat robust. It's a small app, so the blurring of MVC is tolerable if I need to go with the template processor route.

Comment: Me and Aamir had the same answer but he was a bit quicker. :)

Comment: I meant in regards to passing on the page through the request_context. Going to test this and accept his answer, since it was first. Thanks again!